# createSearchChoice select2 and add values from another dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to create a select2 dropdown, that is populated with values after another a value is selected from another dropdown.   I am able to do this using the .each loop:

```
$.each(data, function() {
      $("#subjectId").append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.value +'</option>')
});
```

I need the populated dropdown, subjectId, to also be a createSearchChoice so I can add new elements on the fly.  I am able to use the createSearhChoice and 'form hidden' tag to create the dropdown and add values on the fly.

```
$("#subjectId").select2({
                multiple: false,
                createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
                    if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
                data: [{id: '', text: ''}]
});
```

The problem I am having is I am not able to do both.  Is there a way to have a dropdown populated when another drop down has it's value changed and also use the createSearchChoice to populate values on the fly?

thanks